# How do i scrape a specific url/links from a webpage in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, web, screen-scraping

i am trying to scrape a specific link("https://mobohng.com/breaking-lol-sit-at-home-order-grounds-again/") from a webpage using this flutter package, web_scraper:^0.1.4.
The following is the html format of the link i want to scrape:

```
<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="https://mobohng.com/breaking-lol-sit-at-home-order-grounds-again/">This is the way it goes again again</a></h3>
```

The following is what i have tried so far:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> elementsUrl = webScraper.getElement('h3.entry-title > a.href', ['href']);
```

The problem is, i am getting a null result. My question is what am i doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use package:html and its dom.dart and use querySelector function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> elementsUrl;
elementUrl = webScraper.getElement('h3.entry-title > a', ['href']);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.